# Can questions with "Quantum", "Entanglement", "Wave function" and "Superposition" go straight to a moderator for review?

Tags: feature-request

I'm noticing that questions that involve lots of QM jargon tend to also be very poor and subjective, and seem to be adding to the overall noise level on the site. Is there a way that such questions get reviewed before being posted?

Comment: Probably not anytime soon, but it's an interesting idea. You can definitely highlight certain tags and search for these strings... and there may be a general feature idea here for a "sensitive topics"  review queue. It might be useful to put specific guidance in the tour/new questions page that certain topics  demand specific theoretical context, and that vague fishing-expeditions will be closed.

Comment: I've had the same thought before. It's too far from my speciality to write a definitive answer to those sorts of questions and the quandaries they raise (which seem to be eternal variations of the same).

I think there's technical limitations that make it so that the SE system does not have auto-flag capacities to this level, but it would be great if we could get some.

Comment: I completely agree with this notion although I don't know how feasible it is to implement. A lot of questions that I've seen involving quantum mechanics (recently but also in the past) start out confusing and once you probe the OP you find out they don't really have a good grasp of the terminology or mathematics of what is going on. My first response to that situation is to say something like "you should probably be asking a less philosophical question on physics.se or going back and learning some actual QM" not nobody wants to hear that sort of criticism even if it's valid so it gets hairy.